# anyone knows how to print this pattern in php

Tags: php

Expected output :[image]
my current code only output the pattern but it can't have more comb:

```
    $n = 5;
    $n1 = 4;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j <= $n1; $j++) {

            if (($i == 0 || $i == 5) && ($j  > 0 and $j  < 3)) {
                if (($i == 0 && $j == 1) || ($i == $n && $j != 2)) {
                    printf("&ensp;");
                }
                printf("$i");
            } elseif (($j == 0 || $j == 3) && ($i != 0 and $i != 5)) {
                if ($j == 0 && $i != 1 && $i != 4) {
                    printf("");
                } elseif (($j == 3 && $i != 1 && $i != 4)) {
                    printf("&ensp;&ensp;");
                } elseif ($j == 0) {
                    printf("&ensp;");
                }
                printf("$i");
            } else {
                printf("&ensp;");
            }
        }
        echo "<be>";


    
`
```

this is the output  the only problem is how do i multiply the comb.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun I wrote it in JS, but probably pretty straightforward to convert to PHP (`String.repeat => str_repeat`, `[].push => array_push`, `[].slice => array_slice`, etc)

```js
const arr = [];
const output = (x=1, y=1) => {
    for (let k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        arr.push([' '.repeat(5-k), k, '  '.repeat(k), k, ' '.repeat(5-k)].join(''))
    }
    for (let k = 5; k <= 10; k++) {
        arr.push([' '.repeat(k-5), 10-k, '  '.repeat(10-k), 10-k, ' '.repeat(k-5)].join(''))
    }
    arr.forEach((row, index) => {
        arr[index] = row + row.substring(1).repeat(x - 1);
    });
    const orig = [...arr.slice(1)]
    for (let i = 1; i < y; i++) {
        arr.push(...orig);
    }
    console.log(arr.join('\n'))
}

output(2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create an array, where 1 = '*' and 0 = ' '.

This is the algorithm in PHP 7 that I have done to create the pattern.

**Note:** I have made changes to optimize the code

```
<?php
$max = 6;

// Arg
$arg1 = 2;
$arg2 = 2;

// Change to pair size when is non
if ($max % 2 != 0) {
    ++$max;
}

// Matrix with zero values
$t = \array_fill(0, $max * $arg1 - $arg1 + 1, \array_fill(0, $max * $arg2 - $arg2 + 1, 0));

// Lower: start left position
$lower = $max / 2 - 1;

// Upper: start right postion
$upper = $lower + 1;

// Set pattern in matrix
for ($i = 0, $n = $max - 1; $i <= $n; $i++, $lower--, $upper++) {
    for ($a1 = 0; $a1 < $arg1; $a1++) {
        for ($a2 = 0; $a2 < $arg2; $a2++) {
            $y = $i + $max * $a1 - $a1;
            $p = $max * $a2 - $a2;
            // Set pixel pattern
            $t[$y][$lower + $p] = $t[$y][$upper + $p] = 1;
        }
    }
    // Restart lower?
    if ($lower == 0) {
        $lower = $max;
    }
    // Restart upper?
    if ($upper == $n) {
        $upper = -1;
    }
}
echo '<pre>', \PHP_EOL;
foreach ($t as $r) {
    foreach ($r as $v) {
        if ($v) {
            echo '*';
        } else {
            echo ' ';
        }
    }
    echo \PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
  **   **  
 *  * *  * 
*    *    *
*    *    *
 *  * *  * 
  **   **  
 *  * *  * 
*    *    *
*    *    *
 *  * *  * 
  **   **
```